# NUnit test and how to initialize DependencyManager.Resolve

Tags: c#, nunit

I have the following code that I need to initiate within my integration test in my C# NUnit test.

How can I initialize the DependencyManager.Resolve method please?

Many thanks,

**Unit test calls this method**

```
public static Account GetCustomer(string databaseName)
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(databaseName);

    using(DbCommand cmd = db...)
    {

    }
}
```

**CreateDatabase method**

```
public static Database CreateDatabase(string name)
{
    IDbFactory factory = DependencyManager.Resolve<IDbFactory>();
    return factory.GetDatabase(name);
}
```

**Unit test**

```
[Test]
public void When_I_Call_GetCustomer_A_Customer_Is_Returned()
{
    var result = CustomerAccount.GetCustomer(..);
}
```

**Update**

DependencyManager implementation shown below

```
public class DependencyManager
{
    public static T Resolve<T>(string key = "", ParamDictionary parameters = null)
    {
        return Resolver.Resolve<T>(key, parameters);
    }
}


private static volatile IDependencyResolver resolver;
...

public static IDependencyResolver Resolver
{
    get { return DependencyManager.resolver; }
}
```

It eventually gets to

```
public class CastleDependencyContainer : IDependencyBuilder, IDependencyResolver
```

Comment: That is the reason why static method considered as "bad practice" from testability point of view.

Comment: `DependencyManager` isn't in the .Net framework, as far as I can tell. Is it from your code or a third party?

Comment: It's internal code

Comment: .. so how can anyone who can't see the code tell you how to initialize it?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem, do you need DependencyManager to return a specific inctance of IDbFactory for the purposes of your unit test?

Comment: Would it be possible to include some of your DependencyManager code please?

Comment: Thanks @mark_h I've provided that with my update just now.  Also, I just want to the unit test to execute the sql query (as opposed to mocking it out)

Comment: What is Resolver? It looks like a DI container but it's not one I've heard of.

Comment: Sounds like an implementation of the service locator (anti) pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern